# Svelte script for parsing only key filtered from json

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, mapping, svelte

I have a very strange issue, and I'm not able to fix it.
I have this Json response from an API:

```
{
 "type::new":"#000000",
 "type::closed":"#000011",
 "priority::low":"#FFFFFF",
 "priority::normal":"#FF0000",
 "priority::high":"#FFFF00",
 "type::bug":"#001100"
}
```

I need to get, for example, only key that start with "type", so:

```
"type::new", "type::closed", "type::bug"
```

and assign each element to an array object with these values:

```
items: [
{
    id: 'type::new',
    value: 'type::new',
    title: 'type::new'
},
{
    id: 'type::closed',
    value: 'type::closed',
    title: 'type::closed'
},
{
    id: 'type::bug',
    value: 'type::bug',
    title: 'type::bug'
}
]
```

I'm in a Svelte script, I tryed this but it not works (and I'm stopping only on get without filter them) [response is a result of fetch API):

```
const data = await response.json();
return data.map((item: any) => ({ id: item.key(), value: item.key(), title: item.key()}));
```

Thank you so much :)

Comment: You can't `map()` object properties directly, but you can map `Object.keys(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, you can't `map()` objects properties, but you can loop them over using `Object.keys()` or `for...in`.

```js
const data = {
  "type::new": "#000000",
  "type::closed": "#000011",
  "priority::low": "#FFFFFF",
  "priority::normal": "#FF0000",
  "priority::high": "#FFFF00",
  "type::bug": "#001100"
}


//
// USING for...in
//
const results = []

for (let key in data) {
  if (key.includes('type::')) {
    results.push({ id: key, value: key, title: key })
  }
}

console.log(results)



//
// USING Object.keys(), filter() AND map()
//
const results2 = Object.keys(data).filter(item => item.includes('type::')).map(key => {
  return { id: key, value: key, title: key }
})

console.log(results2)
```